# Multiple queries using PDO

Tags: php

So here's my problem : 
I have different queries on a same PHP page (SELECT queries). Each of these queries work fine separately (I have tested them).
These queries are used to make html tables and then to display graphs with a jquery plugin (the users are able to choose the graphs that they want to display on the page thanks to check-boxes).However, I can display only one graph because there's only one query that works when I refresh the page. The others return no result. I have tried using the function NextRowset() with a do-while but it doesn't work (even though there is no error)
Here is a part of my code so that you can see :

```
foreach($_POST['choixCourbe'] as $choixCourbe) {

if ($choixCourbe=='courantBatterie') {  

    $sql = 'SELECT batteryCurrent FROM data ORDER BY id' 
    $stmt = $bdd->prepare($sql1);                           
    $stmt->execute();           
    do {        
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);} while ($stmt->nextRowset());                     

    if ($rows == false) { echo 'No result';}

    else { /*create table*/ }
    $stmt->closeCursor();
}

if ($choixCourbe=='courantSolaire') {   

    $sql = 'SELECT sunCurrent FROM data ORDER BY id';

    $stmt = $bdd->prepare($sql);                        
    $stmt->execute();
    do {            
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);} while ($stmt->nextRowset());                     

    if ($rows == false) {echo 'No result';}

    else {/*create table*/}
    $stmt->closeCursor();
}
}
```

On the code above, the user should be able to see two graphs when he clicks on the two corresponding check-boxes (I have checked that both values of the check-boxes are correctly taken into account so that's not the problem) but there's currently one graph.

Any idea of what the problem is ?

Thanks for your answers,

Sophie

Comment: Can't you please, 1. **Format** your code to let one read it without constant scrolling. 2. Get rid of all that pointless stuff you tried to add out of wild guess, leaving the code in the initial state? thank you

Comment: What this code `while ($stmt->nextRowset());` is for?

Comment: It is because I have read on the internet that PDO cannot return multiple queries. That's why I used the function nextRowset() that is implemented with a do-while on PHP documentation. But I'm not sure if that works

Comment: That's why I asked ou to get rid of all the useless code you added.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, the problem is as silly as two contradicting conditions,

```
if ($choixCourbe=='courantBatterie') { 
and
if ($choixCourbe=='courantSolaire') {
```

of which only one can be executed at a time, *obviously*.

So, the problem is rather HTML related. make your checkbox names like `choixCourbe[]` and then use `in_array()` in PHP to test if particular value were selected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had forgotten to write the "foreach" that I use to test which values of the checkboxes are selected. My checkboxes have already names like choixCourbe[]

Comment: Then debug your code. See if it even enters other blocks.